# Some dynamical and Bundle questions arising from certain map $P:TS^{n}\to S^{n}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, fibre-bundles, hamiltonian-mechanics

Define  the  map $$P:TS^{n}\to S^{n}  \;\;\;\text{by}\;\;  P((x,v))=\frac{x+v}{\parallel x+v \parallel}$$  where $$TS^{n}=\{(x,v)\in S^{n} \
\times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\mid v \perp x \}$$

This  map is used in the  book of  Alain Hatcher, Algebraic topology,  to  give  a proof  for the fact that every vector field on even spheres must vanish  at some point of the sphere.

**Question:**

> 1. Does  $P$ define  a  (nontrivial)  fiber bundle?
> 2. Define  the  Hamiltonian function $H:TS^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$  with $H(x,v)={\parallel P(x,v)-x \parallel}^{2} $  where the  latter norm is the standard Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. What can be said about the  dynamical  behavior of the  corresponding  Hamiltonian vector  field $X_{H}$? Are there  any periodic  orbit?
> 3. Assume that $V$ is  a vector  field on the  sphere. To $V$, we  associate a self map $f(x)=P(x,V(x))$ on the  sphere. Are there  some relations  between the  continuous  dynamics  of  $V$  and the  discrete dynamics  of $f$. Note  that $V$  and  $f$ have  the same fixed points.

Comment: $P$ is (up to a mild re-parametrization) the restriction of the exponential map for the tangent bundle of $S^n$.  So 1, yes.  $H$ is basically a re-scaled length of $v$, that answers (2).   (3) can similarly be answered.

Comment: @RyanBudney  $H$ is  not  a  re-scaled  length of $v$, since the lenght of $v$ is  an unbounded function but $H$ is  a  bounded function! Could you please elaborate your comment. I think your comments is  not clear.

Comment: @RyanBudney  Do you mean that $X_{H}$ equal geodesic flow vector field up to a constant multiplier? Do you  mean that $H$ is globally equal to $\parallel v \parallel ^2$  up to a  constant?How  can (3)  be answered immediately?

Comment: $P$ is pretty much precisely the exponential map if you re-scale the input vector by a non-linear function of its length.  i.e. re-scale the input vector's length by $L \longmapsto 1/\sqrt{1+L^2}$.  Exponentiate that vector, this gives you $P$.  So your function $H$ is a similar non-linear rescaling of the length squared of the input vector.

Comment: @RyanBudney  But why does this imply that $X_{H}$ has the same dynamic as the geodesic flow?Moreover, what about the third part of my question?

Comment: @RyanBudney  Do you  mean $P(x,V)=exp(V/\sqrt{1+\parallel V \parallel^2}$? If you mean this equality, I think some thing is missing, for example it is not the case for $n=1$.

Answer (score 4):

There is a wonderful trick - I think promulgated by Moser - for viewing Hamiltonian flows on the cotangent bundle of the sphere as the reduction of a   Hamiltonian flow on the ambient phase space of (x,p)'s , i.e on  ${\mathbb R}^{n+1} \times{\mathbb R}^{n+1}$ and  which shows that your flow is in fact a geodesic flow running at twice the speed.
View the sphere as the space of rays through the origin, so orbits
of the ${\mathbb R}^+$ action $x \mapsto \lambda x$.  The cotangent lift of this action to the ambient phase space is $(x,p) \mapsto (\lambda x, p/\lambda)$.  The momentum map for this scaling action is $J(x,p) = \langle x, p \rangle$. The reduced space at $J =0$ is canonically the cotangent bundle of the sphere.  A Hamiltonian H for the cotangent bundle of the sphere becomes then a function on the ambient phase space which   is homogeneous of degree 0 -- i.e invariant --
with respect to this  scaling.  Example: the Hamiltonian for geodesic flow on the sphere  is $H_{geod} = (1/2)|x|^2 |p|^2$.  Your Hamiltonian, made homogeneous of degree 0 , is $H = |(x/|x|- |x|p)|^2 = (1 - 2<x,p> + |x|^2|p|^2)$. But we must fix $J = 0$.  So $H = 1 + 2 H_{geod}$ -- your
flow is geodesic flow, running at twice the speed.

Comment: Prof. Montgomery  Thank you  very  much for your  answer and your  attention to my question. I am sorry for my delay. May be I am missing  some thing but the  Hamiltonian $H$ which I defined is a bounded  function but the geodesic  Hamiltonian is not. So, how they differ  by  a  constant?

Comment: Ali ,  what symplectic form did you want to use on the tangent bundlewould you write down, in some coordinates, what your symplectic form is, or what your vector field is? The reason I ask -- $TS^n$ does not have an intrinsic symplectic form, but  $T^* S^n$ does.    I was assuming you were using the standard Riemannian metric to identify the tangent and cotangent bundles in your question.

Comment: sorry, edit system cut me off; 1) you have a point, about bounded/unboundednss.  (2) what is   your symplectic form, or your Ham vector field on the tangent bundle of the sphere?

Comment: As you said, the  sympletcic structure is  coming from the  cotangent bundle via isomorphism between the tangent and  cotangent  bundle via inner product inheriting from $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. But  before going to the  Hamiltonian vector  field, please consider your equation $H=1+2H_{\text{geod}}$. The  left part is  a  globally  bounded function but the right part is not. How can they be equal?